# ¿Cómo puedo dejar radios con label en la misma linea?

Tags: css, html5

Tengo 3 radios, cada uno dentro de un label en el que escribo un nombre, para que al hacer click sobre este también se haga click en el radio. El problema es que no logro colocarlos a todos de forma horizontal en la misma linea, les dejo el código html y una imágen de cómo deberían quedar:

```css
label {
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="radio" />Primero</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="radio" />Segundo</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="radio" />Tercero</label>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Comparte tu codigo CSS, el codigo que estas mostrando ordenaria los elementos uno tras otro como la primera imagen

Comment: He ingresado el css que tenian los label

Comment: Aun con ese codigo los input se muestran lado al lado como se supone que esperas, debes proveer un ejemplo de tu problema para que podamos ayudarte; crea un fragmento de codigo donde se replique el problema que tienes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes agregarle float:left en el estilo de la etiqueta label

ejemplo:

```
<label style="float:left"><input checked  type="radio"value="1">Primero</label>
<label style="float:left"><input  type="radio"value="2">Segundo</label>
<label style="float:left"><input  type="radio"value="3">Tercero</label>
```

Comment: Lo aplique pero siguen estando en vertical

Comment: puede que tenga que ver con width: 20%; con respecto al contenedor de los labels

Comment: Eso me soluciono el problema, te lo agradezco un montón.

Answer (score 1):

Saca los labels de los inputs y tendras el resultado que deseas.

```html
 <input type="radio" value="value1" name="group1">Grupo 1
 <input type="radio" value="value2" name="group2">Grupo 2
```

Comment: El problema es que pierden la capacidad de checkearse si haces click en el texto.

Answer (score 0):

Cambie el `div` ke los contenia por una tabla....y `align center` y `justify content`. ..y kitale el `display flex`...los hace perder cualidades....espero te ayude

Comment: ¿A qué te referís con "los hace perder cualidades"? Por cierto, leé [answer].